# Why is my c++ regex matching correctly, but not returning the correct value?

Tags: c++, regex

I have a regex for matching terms of a polynomial, which I will use to implement a function for turning a string into a polynomial class. You can see the regex demoed [here](https://regex101.com/r/JHRJE5/1) with the correct matches being generated. However, when I try to implement it, my program finds the matches properly, but prints them bizarrely to the screen. For instance:

```
-21323x^5+1233x4+123x^2-1232
Trying to match: -21323x^5+1233x4+123x^2-1232
-21323x^5
Trying to match: +1233x4+123x^2-1232
1233x4
Trying to match: +123x^2-1232
12xx^2
Trying to match: -1232
-1232
```

In this case, for some reason it prints `12xx^2` rather than `123x^2`

And another:

```
-1234x^5+789x4+6x^2-567+123x
Trying to match: -1234x^5+789x4+6x^2-567+123x
-1234x^5
Trying to match: +789x4+6x^2-567+123x
789x4
Trying to match: +6x^2-567+123x
x^22
Trying to match: -567+123x
-567
Trying to match: +123x
23xx
```

In this case it shows `x^22` instead of `6x^2` and `23xx` instead of `123x`.

This is my code:

```
Poly* Poly::fromString(std::string str) {
    Poly* re = new Poly;
    bool returnNull = true;
    std::regex r_term("((-?[0-9]*)x(\\^?([0-9]+))?|-?[0-9]+)");
    std::smatch sm;
    while(std::regex_search(str, sm, r_term)) {
        returnNull = false;
        std::cout << "Trying to match: " << str << std::endl;
        str = sm.suffix().str();
        std::cout << sm.str() << std::endl;
    }

    if(returnNull) {
        delete re;
        return nullptr;
    } else return re;
}
```

Comment: Move the assignment `str = sm.suffix().str();` below the line where you print `sm.str()`. `smatch` doesn't hold a copy of the match, only iterators into the original string. By modifying the string from under it, your program invalidates those iterators and therefore exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you very much. Please add this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

While Igor correctly notices the issue with your current code, I think all you need is to get full pattern matches, and for this purpose, I'd rather suggest using a regex iterator:

```
std::regex r("(-?[0-9]*)x(\\^?([0-9]+))?|-?[0-9]+");
std::string s = "-21323x^5+1233x4+123x^2-1232";
for(std::sregex_iterator i = std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), r);
                         i != std::sregex_iterator();
                         ++i)
{
    std::smatch m = *i;
    std::cout << "Match value: " << m.str() << '\n';
    std::cout << "Group 1 value: " << m.str(1) << '\n';
    std::cout << "Group 2 value: " << m.str(2) << '\n';
    std::cout << "Group 3 value: " << m.str(3) << '\n';
}
```

See the [C++ demo online](https://ideone.com/hUsTID).

The pattern details:

- `-?` - 1 or 0 hyphens
- `[0-9]*` - 0 or more digits
- `x` - a literal char `x`
- `(\\^?([0-9]+))?`  - 1 or 0 sequences of:

  - `\\^?` - an optional (1 or 0) `^` symbols
  - `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits
- `|` - or
- `-?`  - an optional hyphen/minus
- `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits.

Comment: I am actually interested in using submatches, as it allows me to instantly access my coefficient and power.

Comment: Ok, keep them, but I'd still suggest to remove the outer brackets since the whole match is already inside Group 0. Also, using the iterator does not require creating a copy of your initial string that will get destroyed during your code execution.

Comment: I agree, that seems like a better idea. The reason I had the outer match group was because I mistakenly believed that you needed them to use the | regex operator.

Comment: The `|` separated alternatives are necessary to be grouped when you are using them in a larger regex and the parts on the left and right are to be applied to all the alternatives. Say, `^(ac|bc)$` will match two strings only `ac` and `bc`, but `^ac|bc$` will match `ac` at the beginning of a string (say, `ac` in `ace`) and `bc` at the end of the string (say, `bc` in `abc`, but not `bc` in `abcd`).